# Can't install Ubuntu with Windows 7

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-7, ubiquity

In spanish:

Hola.

Estoy teniendo problemas para instalar Ubuntu 10.04 de 32 bits en una pc que tiene Windows 7 Ultimate preinstalado de 64 bits.

Puntualmente el problema es que al insertar el cd de Ubuntu y comenzar la instalacion, no reconoce que haya otro sistema operativo en el disco. La unica opcion que me da es la de instalar Ubuntu en todo el disco. Intente creando una nueva particion en el disco desde Windows pero tampoco la reconoce: Ve a todo el disco como vacio.

Desde Windows veo que hay dos particiones, una la principal y otra la paricion del sistema que crea Windows 7 de 100 Mb. El disco es de 1 Tb.

Wubi tampoco funciona. Luego de instalar y bootear desde ubuntu, muestra un error diciendo que no encuentra el directorio raiz y que no puede continuar la instalacion, o algo asi.

Escucho sugerencias. Muchas gracias.

---

En Ingles:

Hi.

I'm having trouble to install Ubuntu 10.04 (32 bits) on a computer with Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bits).

The problem is that when I insert the Ubuntu's cd and begin the installation, it doesn't recognize Windows on the hard disk. It only allows me to install Ubuntu over all the disk. I tried creating a new partition in the hard disk on Windows but neither recognizes it: See all the disk as empty.

On Windows I see two partitions, the main one and a system's partition of 100 Mb, which Windows creates on it installation. The hard disk has 1 Tb.

Wubi doesn't work either. After install and booting Ubuntu, it shows an error saying that doesn't find the root directory and the installation can't continue, or something like that.

Thank you.

Comment: A word of advice, please try latest ubuntu 12.10 if you are not constrained to use 10.04. It's too old for newer hardwares. Secondly try disabling UEFI if enabled. Also the disk type should be `BASIC` not `Dynamic` (you can see this info in windows disk management console, `diskmgmt.msc` , see something like disk0)

Comment: This issue could be related to the Advanced Format for newer hard drives. 10.04 should already have support for them built in, but I would recommend installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_format

Comment: @Web-E suggesting 12.10 for installation is bad advice. Not everyone wants to upgrade every six months and especially the first release after an LTS release isn't a good choice (released earlier and earlier abandoned).

Answer (score 0):

Aver. Quieres poner el ubuntu de 32 bits, en un ordenador que tiene preinstalado el windows de 64 bits....... eso es raro. Ti sistema tiene que ser de 64 bits   Intenta con el ubuntu de 64 bits

**English:** From what I understood, you want to put 32 bits ubuntu in an orderer that has 64 bits Windows pre-installed? This is rare, Your system has to have 64 bits, try with the 64 bits ubuntu.